# xfs_quota and quota commands not working for NFS clients

Tags: centos, rhel, nfs, xfs, quota

I've been bumping up against this issue for years, but have never been able to find a resolution.  Prior to RHEL7 (i.e. RHEL 5, RHEL 6, and CentOS 6), I was able to...

1. Implement user quotas on my NFS servers, via the `usrquota` option in the `/etc/fstab` file
2. Mount the NFS shares to a cluster of various EL clients (RHEL 5 & 6, CentOS 6, Fedora 17 thru 21, Pidora, and even Raspbian)
3. Enforce quotas across **all** of those clients
4. Query quotas via the `quota` command on **ALL** of those clients

***Problem:***

With CentOS7, I have made the jump to XFS (from ext4), and  I am able to do all of the above **except** "*4. Query quotas via the `quota` command on **ALL** of those clients*", and the `xfs_quota` command **also does not** report any information relating to the XFS formatted file systems mounted from the NFS Server with quotas enabled.  The CentOS7 NFS Server **does** enforce those quotas, which is useful to my administration of the NFS Server, but frustrating for hundreds of NFS Client users as well as when supporting users who repeatedly run into quota limitations.

The following "Workaround" allows users to query disk usage of their NFS mounted file systems, but is **not** an accurate or sufficient substitution for `quota`/`xfs_quota` queries, nor is it an intuitive solution for most users...

```
du ‐s .[A‐z]* * | sort ‐n
```

I've danced around this issue long enough, and would really appreciate if this community could assist with my understanding why reporting user quotas across my XFS formatted NFS shares is not working.  RHEL support, and CentOS support forums are all turning up empty.

Assistance would be appreciated!

***Notes:***

- I have the `uquota,gquota` options in the `/etc/fstab` file on the
  NFS Server, as so...

  ```
  /dev/mapper/nfs-home  /home        xfs    defaults,uquota,gquota    0 0
  ```
- The following is the NFS mount entry in the NFS Client `/etc/fstab` file...

  ```
  123.45.67.89:/        /home        nfs    rw,hard,intr,bg           0 0
  ```
- The `rpcbind`, `quotad` and `rquotad` TCP & UDP ports are opened in the Server's firewall.
- There are subnet entries for the `rpcbind`, `quotad`, and `rquotad` services in the `/etc/hosts.allow` file.
- A `df` query on the NFS Client(s) shows the mounted NFS shares, while the `xfs_quota -c 'df'` command does **not** return any NFS mounted file systems.

***I am happy to provide more information on the Client-Server relationship if anyone shows interest.***